# Como efetuar um refresh na tela no Angular?

Tags: angular

Observem o código abaixo;

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-node-paginate',
  templateUrl: './node-paginate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./node-paginate.component.css']
})
export class NodePaginateComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private location: Location) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.load();
  }

  load() {
      location.reload()
    }
```

Esse código acima ele efetua um refresh na tela ininterruptamente, mas o que de fato preciso é que ele faça somente um refresh.

Meu objetivo é quando o usuário acessar a pagina, a pagina consiga efetuar um refresh de tela, mas precisa ser somente um refresh e não vários como está acontecendo hoje.

A pedido de  **Guilherme Costamilam**

Esse é problema que estou tendo também;
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando a **versão 6** do Angular.

Eu tentei também dessa forma para saber o que saiu no console.log;

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-node-paginate',
  templateUrl: './node-paginate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./node-paginate.component.css']
})
export class NodePaginateComponent implements OnInit {
  public innerWidth: any;



  constructor(private location: Location) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
      console.log(this.innerWidth);
      this.load();
  }

  load() {
    console.log(sessionStorage);
    //Session storage salva os dados como string
    (sessionStorage.refresh == 'true' || !sessionStorage.refresh) && location.reload();
    sessionStorage.refresh = false;
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

}
```

E tive esse resultado;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não entendo porque não está reconhecendo a variável `refresh`

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 2):

De forma simples, guarda em session/local storage se já foi ou não recarregado e usa como condicional para carregar novamente:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.load();
}

load() {
  //Session storage salva os dados como string
  (sessionStorage.refresh == 'true' || !sessionStorage.refresh) && location.reload();
  sessionStorage.refresh = false;
}
```

Você também pode ter uma variável na url que defina isso, porém, em vez de apenas recarregar, teria que redirecionar para outra url, por exemplo, `dominio.com/foo/true/` irá recarregar, `dominio.com/foo/false/` ou `dominio.com/foo` não irão recarregar, dai no seu componente você verifica o valor da variável na url em vez do session/local storage

Comment: a variavel `refresh` não foi reconhecida no meu projeto Angular.

Comment: Editei a reposta com uma correção, pode ser isso, se não, de um `console.log(sessionStorage.refresh)` no angular e comente o `reload`, aparece o valor eperado?

Comment: não tem como eu dar um `console.log(sessionStorage.refresh)` porque ele diz que a propriedade  refresh não existe do tipo 'Storage'

Comment: está dando erro de compilação? Se é, define como `: any`. Testei aqui e funcionou normal, qual a sua versão?

Comment: eu atualizei minha postagem, poderia dar uma olhada por favor.

Comment: Constamilam eu tentei definir a variavel refresh como any assim `   public refresh: any;` como variavel global, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Tenta usar `window.sessionStorage`

Comment: tentei usar dessa forma `window.sessionStorage.refresh == 'true'`não pegou

Comment: faz um `console.log(sessionStorage)`, apareceu o objeto no console do navegador? Tenta também `sessionStorage.get('refresh')` e `sessionStorage.set('refresh', true)`, se não funcionar faz o mesmo com `localStorage`

Comment: acabei de realizar o console.log e conseguir encontrar o refresh, porém não consigo entender porque não consegue reconhecer a variável `refresh`, por favor da uma olhada na minha postagem, acabei de atualizar.

Comment: O problema é a tipagem do ts que emcomoda as vezes, com o `get` e `set` não funcionou?

Comment: não funciona o get e o set.

Comment: Você quer eu disponibilize o meu projeto através do github  para você dar uma olhada?  Ele é um projeto simples, não tem integração com banco de dados!

Answer (score 2):

Eu enfrentei um problema similar, para resolver eu coloquei uma variável no meu `Service`, algo como:

```js
export class MyService {
  reload = true;
  constructor() { }
}
```

E em meu componente criei a função `reload` que muda a rota e depois volta para a rota atual (não sei se em seu caso resolveria, pois é um reload apenas de componente e não da aplicação como um todo):

```js
  reload() {
    if (this.myService.reload) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['minha-rota']);
        this.myService.reload = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Com isso basta coloca-la para rodar no `ngOnInit`:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.reload();
  }
```

**Obs:** O meu caso era um pouco diferente, eu tinha que fazer `reload` após determinada ação do usuário, tentei adaptar para a sua realidade, não sei se terá algum efeito colocateral.

Answer (score 2):

Talvez você possa realizar com `Session Storage` mesmo, porém eu faria de uma forma um pouco diferente.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.load();
}

load() {
  const HAS_RELOAD = 'hasReload';  // Ao invés de passar a string 'hasRealod' diretamente é melhor criar uma constante para evitar erros de digitação
  const hasReload = sessionStorage.getItem(HAS_RELOAD);
  if (!hasReload) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(HAS_RELOAD, 'true');
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi seu segundo código está funcionando, visto que você postou o resultado do console. Então após efetuar o primeiro *refresh* ele para por ali visto que o `sessionStorage.refresh` tem o valor `false`. Já o primeiro código realmente está em loop mas basta utilizar o exemplo do segundo para corrigir o primeiro.

Código testado e funcionando retirado do seu exemplo:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log('ngOnInit', (new Date()).toTimeString());
      this.load();
  }

  load() {
    console.log('sessionStorage', sessionStorage);
    (sessionStorage.refresh == 'true' || !sessionStorage.refresh) 
        && location.reload();
    sessionStorage.refresh = false;
  }
}
```

> Porém não entendo porque não está reconhecendo a variável refresh

Existe uma validação de tipagem no TypeScript e por esta razão você está recebendo a mensagem "*TS: A propriedade refresh não existe no tipo Storage*" já que realmente a esta propriedade não existe em `localStorage` nem na `sessionStorage`.

Uma solução é utilizar os método `sessionStorage.getItem("refresh")` e `sessionStorage.setItem("refresh", "true")` ao invés de utilizar o modo "Object Like (sessionStorage.minhaPropriedade)". Outra alternativa é tipar como `any`:

```
(<any>(localStorage)).refresh
(localStorage as any).refresh
```

Pesquisando mais um pouco, dentro do VS Code pressione o `ctrl` e clique sob o `sessionStorage`até chegar na definição da sua interface. Lá deve constar a última linha do código abaixo:

```
interface Storage {
    /* ... conteúdo omitido */
    setItem(key: string, value: string): void;
    [name: string]: any;
}
```

Caso não tenha, verifique a versão do seu TSLint ou inclua esta última linha e a mensagem supracitada irá desaparecer.

Referência deste problema: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26083

Answer (score 1):

Cara, é só por quê você criou uma função load() que faz um reload e a colocou no ngInit.
O ngInit executa tudo que está dentro dele ao iniciar uma página, ou seja, virou um loop infinito.

```
iniciou a página > ngInit ativou o load() > reiniciou a página > ngInit ativou o load() > reiniciou a página
```